# Searching an Array VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I wish vba to search a given cell for "ANY" of these phrases and if it should find any of these phrases change the colour of text in another cell Green other wise turn it red.
So far i can get it to search the cell however its marking everything as red even though I know they should be green. I assume it is not searching the entire content of the array.
Here is what i have so far:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim celltxt1 As String, mvarr1, a

    celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("G21:G128").Select
    mvarr1 = Array("Tom", "Alison1", "Paul", "Deb2", "Pr123", "21", "18", "Pie-1", "Run", "Swim")


   For Each a In mvarr1
       If (InStr(1, celltxt1, CStr(a), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then              
            ActiveSheet.Range("I21:I128").Font.Color = vbGreen
      Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("I21:I128").Font.Color = vbRed
      End If
   Next a
End Sub
```

Any advice or suggestion would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
Sub Test()

   Dim celltxt1 As String, mvarr1, a

   celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("G21:G128").Select
   mvarr1 = Array("Tom", "Alison1", "Paul", "Deb2", "Pr123", "21", "18", "Pie-1", "Run", "Swim")

   Dim isFound As Boolean
   isFound = False

   For Each a In mvarr1
     If (InStr(1, celltxt1, CStr(a), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
          isFound = True
          Exit For
     End If
   Next a

   If isFound = True Then
       ActiveSheet.Range("I21:I128").Font.Color = vbGreen
   Else
       ActiveSheet.Range("I21:I128").Font.Color = vbRed
   End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you set the colour for each item in the array, it'll end up red if the last item in the array isn't found, no matter what happened before.

The simplest change would just be to set to red as a default, then set green if any are found.
You can also use `Exit For` to stop looping once the first match is found.

```
Dim clrCell
clrCell = vbRed

For Each a In mvarr1
   If (InStr(1, celltxt1, CStr(a), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then              
       clrCell = vbGreen  
       Exit For
   End If
Next a

ActiveSheet.Range("I21:I128").Font.Color = clrCell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to make each corresponding cell in column "I" a color based on the cell in column "G" then you will want to use the `OFFSET` function.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim celltxt1 As String, mvarr1, a
    Set celltxt = ActiveSheet.Range("G21:G128")
    mvarr1 = Array("Tom", "Alison1", "Paul", "Deb2", "Pr123", "21", "18", "Pie-1", "Run", "Swim")
    For Each b In celltxt
       b.Select
           For Each a In mvarr1
               If (InStr(1, b, CStr(a), vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Color = vbGreen
                   Exit For
               Else
                   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Color = vbRed
               End If
           Next a
    Next b
End Sub
```